# How to setup last row or all rows except last not knowing number of rows in MigLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, miglayout

The following code

```
            int numberofrows = 3;

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Question 12844473");

            frame.setLayout(new MigLayout("fill, debug", "", "[][][150]"));

            for(int i=0; i<numberofrows-1; ++i) {
                frame.add(new JButton("Button #" +i), "wrap");
            }
            frame.add(new JButton("Exit"));

            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
```

provides the following picture

[image]

meaning that third row was affected by setup because each square bracket pattern corresponds to each row.

But how to affect LAST row if number of rows vary? Or how to affect all rows? Or how to affect all rows except last one, while setup last row separately?

I mean not knowing number of rows.

Comment: ehhh - you **don't** want to fiddle with the layout of the rootPane (that will wrack at least the menuBar). Instead, set the layout to the frame's contentPane.

Comment: thanks! but what about main question?

Comment: worksforme (on the contentPane)

Comment: a bounty won't help as long as you insist on wrecking the rootPane - set the layout of the _contentPane_ instead. If doing so doesn't help, show an SSCCE that demonstrates the problem

Comment: @kleopatra I avoided using of `rootPane` you dislike.

Comment: The layout appears exactly like you defined it (second row different than every other row) - what _do_ you want?

Comment: Have you read the question?

Answer (score 3):

You can't generically set the row constraints such that they apply to any number of rows. However, you always know the number of rows, otherwise you can't render that number of rows either. Knowing the number of rows, you can programmatically generate the constraint string. E.g.

```
 String rowConstraint = ""
 rowConstraint += "[]"
 for(int i = 1; i < numberOfRows - 1; i++) {
    rowConstraint += "[150]"
 }     
 rowConstraint += "[]"

 frame.setLayout(new MigLayout("fill, debug", "", rowConstraint));
```

Comment: _always know the number of rows_ not knowing seems to be the problem (as far as I understand the rather unclear question :-)

Comment: @Confusion this is what I was suspected but I will wait for some others to be absolutely sure that `MigLayout` itself does not allow thism what we both just don't know...

Comment: The [documentation of MigLayout](http://www.migcalendar.com/miglayout/whitepaper.html) says: "If there are fewer rows in the format string than there are in the grid cells in that dimension the last gap and row constraint will be used for the extra rows". To me this implies that you can only specify a constraint for 'the remaining rows'. There is no way to specify a constraint for 'the last' row or 'all but the last' row.

Comment: May be there is some stub syntax meaning all first rows?

Comment: @SuzanCioc what do you mean by _all first rows_? There's exactly one per layout ... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You mean that you are in this situation:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Question 12844473");

frame.setLayout(new MigLayout("fill, debug", "", "[][][150]"));

while( 0 != (i = hasRow()))
{
    frame.add(new JButton("Button #" +i), "wrap");
}
```

...and now when `hasRow()` returns 0, it is too late, for you already added a frame on the *previous* iteration and you cannot un-add it and re-add some other way.

You can do it like this:

```
prev = hasRow();
while( 0 != (i = hasRow()))
{
    frame.add(new JButton("Button #" + prev), "wrap");
    prev = i;
}
// Now prev is the value of the last-but-one element returned
// and you can process it differently.
frame.add(new JButton("Button #" + prev));
```

You can adapt this pattern to any method whereby you are returned a row at a time, but do not know whether you will get an EOF instead.

*I am not entering into the matter of whether such a frame adding can be done or not*: this is just a generic off-by-one processing trick I cribbed off a HTML generator.